# React, state change not reflected in callback function

Tags: reactjs

Im new to React and stumbled across an issue I don't understand and can't resolve.
I want to change an internal block size dynamically upon specific window screen width threshold cross.

Here is a sample code I prepared:

```
function X(title) {
  const [myWidth, setMyWidth] = React.useState(200)   
  
  function onResize(){
    if(innerWidth > 1000 && myWidth <= 200){
      console.log(`Make Bigger: `, myWidth)
      setMyWidth(400)
    } else if( innerWidth <= 1000 && myWidth >= 400) {
      console.log(`Make Smaller: `, myWidth)
      setMyWidth(200)
    }
  }
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("HELLO")
    addEventListener('resize', onResize)
  },[])
  
  return (<div>
      <div style={{
          backgroundColor:'red',
          width: myWidth,
          height: 100
        }}>
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>);
}

const el = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<X title='Example Component' />, el);
```

I want to see the `div` block width increase when the `innerWidth` become greater than 1000 and decrease when the `innerWidth` get lower than 1000 BUT I don't want to see the console messages on every listener callback invocation (i.e. every pixel change in the width of the screen).

https://codepen.io/radoslavmarino7/pen/KKoYNWK?editors=0011

Comment: You should include `setMyWidth` as useEffect dependency. Instead of `[]` it should be `[setMyWidth]`

Comment: Why `setMyWidth` and not `myWidth`?

Comment: I think you should include both, if you don't include that dependencies, `onResize` function will always keep the initial state value.

Comment: You should include just `onResize`, it's the only function that is used in the effect. And you should use a linter to always know which functions to include.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using **media queries approach** is a better.

Check this simple implementation.

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .box {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .box {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anayarojo/pen/GRxLrMg)

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Here is the **React approach**, you should include `useEffect` dependencies, like this:

```js
React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("HELLO")
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
    };
  },[myWidth, setMyWidth])
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anayarojo/pen/QWmPdrg?editors=0010)

[Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14066)

Comment: Why `setMyWidth` ?

Comment: If you don't include that dependencies, `onResize` function will always keep the initial state value for `myWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with having the callback being called for every pixel change: given that most of the time the state itself doesn't change, React won't rerender, so it shouldn't really affect performance.
But media queries are indeed probably a better option.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your function `onResize` with a `debounce` and set a timeout. This way the function `onResize` with return an output only after user has stopped performing the action.